# Mount device with specific user rights

Tags: linux, mount

How can I mount a device with specific user rights on start up? I still have some problems figuring it out. I would like to mount the divide with `uid=1000` and `gid=1000`. My current entry to the `/etc/fstab/` file looks like this:

```
dev /var/www vboxsf rw, suid, dev, exec, auto, nouser, async, uid=1000
```

Comment: Don't forget gui=1000. Also, what is the ownership/rights to /var/www. It should be owned by root.

Comment: @skub: The owner of `/var/www/` is root. `dev /var/www vboxsf rw, suid, dev, exec, auto, nouser, async, uid=1000 gui=1000` didin't work so well (Ubuntu removed the entry after a failed restart).

Comment: Your mount source is "dev"??

Comment: @wowpatrick - your mount device should be something like /dev/sda1 it should not be 'dev'.

Comment: @skub: It's a VirtualBox shared folder, so /dev is is right. I figured it out by now, `sudo mount -t vboxsf -o umask=0022,gid=33,uid=33 dev /var/www` works just fine.

Comment: Depending on what the device is for, you may also need to add stuff like "nosuid" for extra security. See `man mount` for the generic mount options and `man [fs name]` for file system-specific ones.

Comment: I've been messing around with this problem in vbox for a while now too. From what I've gathered, the correct solution (to the question you aren't asking) is to add your user into the vboxsf group, and then it doesn't matter who the owner of the files are - you will have permission to edit them. http://alcobrov.blogspot.com/2012/06/add-user-in-vboxsf-group-to-access.html

Answer (score 183, accepted):

To mount a device with certain rights, you can use the `-o Option` directive while mounting the device. To mount the device you described, run:

```
 mount -t deviceFileFormat -o umask=filePermissions,gid=ownerGroupID,uid=ownerID /device /mountpoint
```

For example mounting a VirtualBox shared folder to `/var/www` with `www-data` as owner would look like this:

```
mount -t vboxsf -o umask=0022,gid=33,uid=33 dev /var/www
```

If you want to mount the device on startup, you can add the following entry to your `/etc/fstab` file:

```
 /device /mountpoint deviceFileFormat umask=filePermissions,gid=ownerGroupID,uid=ownerUserID
```

Again, with the same example the entry to the `/etc/fstab` file would look like this:

```
dev /var/www vboxsf umask=0022,gid=33,uid=33
```

For filesystems that does not support mounting as a specific user (like ext4) the above will give the error

```
Unrecognized mount option "uid=33" or missing value
```

to change the owner of an ext4 mount simply run

```
chown username /mountpoint
```

after it has been mounted.

Comment: I was able to use the uid/gid option on ext4.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with mount --bind , i'm using a btrfs file system

Comment: Shouldn't the umask be `umask=0077` instead of `umask=0022` to give permission only owner to read or write? It seems that `umask=0022` will give read permissions to others if I am reading it correctly.
I want that only the user who mount the disk should have read or write permission.

Comment: uid=1000,gid=1000 do not work on btfs filesystem on kde with debian 11 on kernel 5.10.0-8-amd64. The error says: mount: /store1: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda1, missing codepage or helper program, orother error. The complete line from /etc/fstab is: "UUID=755d31e9-4ed0-4a41-9821-dd777f12e3dd /store1         btrfs   uid=1000,gid=1000,noatime,nodiratime 0"