# How to set the owner of a mounted partition in Linux?

Tags: linux, permissions

I have two mechanical HDD's in my computer.I run Windows on disk 0
and Crunchbang on disk 1.
I always have to use elevated privileges in Crunchbang  in order to copy files to the NTFS partition in disk 0.

[image]

As far as i know, the commands like chmod and chown , which are  used
for setting file permissions , only hold for file system objects.
Also i know that , "In Linux everything is a file". i.e, there are special files that represent hardware devices , system information etc..
Since these special files belong to the virtual file system /dev
they should be file system objects and so the commands like chown ,chmod should work on these files.
I have successfully changed the owner and write permissions of the device sda by the command

> chown aswin sda

where as i can neither change the owner / permissions of the mounted partition.
I have tried to set the local user as the owner of the mounted partition and set permissions to read,write,execute.But , still the problem persists.

[image]

Am i missing something ?How to set the permission on this disk so that i can write into it without elevated privileges ?

Comment: You probably mounted it using `/etc/fstab`. Check this: http://superuser.com/questions/320415/linux-mount-device-with-specific-user-rights

Comment: Did you install ntfs-3g?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae ntfs-3g is already the newest version.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should **NOT** touch /dev/sd* permissions (I'm **not** talking about `/media/sda4`). If you did change them, please undo your changes and use the default permissions, because it can interfere with other programs. (I think the default owner/group are `root:disk`)

You have to unmount the disk first in order to change the permissions of the mount folder `/media/Disk`.

```
umount /media/Disk
chown aswin:aswin /media/Disk
mount -va
```

In order to mount the disk contents with a specific user/group id, you can set a specific uid/gid (User ID and Group ID) within `/etc/fstab`. See [Linux - Mount device with specific user rights](https://superuser.com/questions/320415/linux-mount-device-with-specific-user-rights)

Also, you have other solutions other than fstab, meaning GUI-based gnome environment:

```
gvfs-mount -d /dev/sdXY
```

...where it mounts the sdXY (change "X" and "Y" with the appropriate letter&number) partition and sets the user as the owner. Gnome environment also allows to click on a partition on the left side menu of nautilus (the file manager) and it auto-mounts the partition.

Comment: +1 for `gvfs-mount` ! With `mount` alone, I didn't managed to allow a standard user to "own" the mount (i.e. allow non-root to unmount) without editing fstab or mtab.

Comment: Can this answer be updated for `gio`?  On Ubuntu 19.04, run: 
`$ gvfs-mount`, get: 
```This tool has been deprecated, use 'gio mount' instead.
See 'gio help mount' for more info.```

Answer (score 0):

After spending some time checking the way how to set a specific owner and group after the mounting has successfully happened, it can be achieved in two ways:

- Depends of the partition filesystem, because depends on that we are gonna identified the possible options parameters.

  - https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html#FILESYSTEM-SPECIFIC_MOUNT_OPTIONS
  - https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/fstab.5.html (check the `The fourth field` header)
- You can apply permissions through `chmod` (common permissions) or [setfacl](https://linux.die.net/man/1/setfacl) (advanced access control list).

I really hope that the information provided can be helpful for somebody.